# Tasking in SPARK requires sequential elaboration

Tags: ada, gnat, spark-ada

I'm currently learning Ada during a university course on real-time programming languages and have a question about SPARK.

I'm working on a project with a task that monitors an off-grid power supply. This task is crucial for machine safety and should therefore be as error free as possible, say proven with SPARK.

I get this weird error that I was not able to find a fix for `11:14 tasking in SPARK requires sequential elaboration (SPARK RM 9(2)) violation of pragma SPARK_Mode`

The original code is a little long but I was able to get the same error with a minimal example.

The specification:

```
pragma Profile (Ravenscar);
pragma SPARK_Mode;

with System;

package simple_monitoring is

   function sign (val : in Float) return Float
     with Pre => val >= 10.0;

   task type myTask is
   end myTask;

end simple_monitoring;
```

The implementation:

```
pragma Profile (Ravenscar);
pragma SPARK_Mode;

with Ada.Real_Time; use Ada.Real_Time;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

package body simple_monitoring is

   function sign (val : in Float) return Float is
      res : Float;
   begin
      pragma Assert (val >= 10.0);
      res := 100.0 / val;

      return res;

   end sign;

   task body myTask is
      TASK_PERIOD : constant Time_Span := Milliseconds (100);
      next_time : Time := Clock;

      myVar : Float;
   begin
      loop
         Put_Line ("Running task");

         myVar := sign (20.0);

         next_time := next_time + TASK_PERIOD;
         delay until next_time;
      end loop;
   end myTask;

end simple_monitoring;
```

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the extra configuration pragma

```ada
pragma Partition_Elaboration_Policy (Sequential);
```

(see [ARM H.6](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-H-6.html)). For the example you give, this only needs to be placed on the spec; but in general it needs to be a program-wide configuration pragma.

You arrange this by having a file, say `gnat.adc`, containing for example

```ada
pragma Profile (Ravenscar);
pragma Partition_Elaboration_Policy (Sequential);
```

and referencing it in package `Builder` in your GNAT project file:

```ada
package Builder is
   for Global_Configuration_Pragmas use "gnat.adc";
   ...
```

Comment: Does setting the partition elaboration policy to sequential have any direct disadvantages? What are other possible policies?

Comment: At least Concurrent. I gave a link above to the ARM Annex H Section 6 (Pragma Partition_Elaboration_Policy); the same section in the Annotated ARM is [here](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-H-6.html) and has a little more detail. That’s about all I know! There are some changed behaviours, but for correct programs I doubt you’d notice them. The advantage of Sequential for software that has to be reliable is that tasks can’t start/interrupts can’t happen until everything is ready to go (i.e. you won’t get any access-before-elaboration errors).

Comment: Looks like sequential is totally fine for my application and moreover required for SPARK. I set the respective pragma and the errors disappeared. Perfect!